# Is possible to declare character type in Python?

Tags: python, char

I tried my best to declare a variable that shows `char` type when I call `type(my_variable)`.

Every attempt shows type `string`.

Please guide me:

- Is there a way to declare variables with a character type in Python like in Java or C++?
- Does a character type exist in Python?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html

Comment: Grab some basic first.[https://developer.rhino3d.com/guides/rhinopython/python-datatypes/]

Comment: You don't declare variable types in Python anyway. Python is not Java or C.